# Strange behavior in php

Tags: javascript

I was trying to access an image under the meme folder on my root directory . Its a code in Javascript that uses php

```
 <script>
 window.onload = function ()
   {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "/meme\\"+'<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>' + ".png";      
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
  Meme(img, can);
  } 
  </script>

 img.src = "/meme/"+'<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>' + ".png"; 
 img.src = "meme\\"+'<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>' + ".png"; 
 img.src = "meme/"+'<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>' + ".png";
 img.src = "/meme\\"+'<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>' + ".png";
```

They all gave me the results but now I am confused. The first backslash I guess is due to relative or absolute path. My question is which one is the right way to do it ? or all these are right

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also, this is not PHP.

Comment: Where do you call the script from?

Comment: what are you trying yo do exactly?  is that javascript with php?

Comment: This appears to be javascript.

Comment: can you show your code? since it looks like you have some javascript inside a loop of php and just bad code. so show the rest. other wise you will keep my -1

Comment: There is no benefit to concatenating a seperate segment for the PHP script, just leave it inline with the rest of your filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to guarantee that *any* page on your site accesses the `/meme` directory, use the preceding forward slash (`/`).

The *only* reason all of those are working is because you're calling this code from a page in the domain's root directory. (for example, `site.com/index.php`)

If you were to **not** include the preceding forward slash and then called it from a nested page, such as `site.com/subdir/subpage.php`, it wouldn't work.

The code best suited for your issue is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    img.src = "/meme/<?php echo $phpvalue; ?>.png"; 
</script>
```

In this case, there is no need to concatenate `$phpvalue` into `img.src`.

---

Furthermore, it's standard practice to use forward slashes (`/`) when denoting URLs and file paths in web development.

Not all platforms are guaranteed to understand a backslash as a file separator. (Additionally, it's messy to type `\\` for every file separator.)